# inserting spaces between two hashtags until it hits 5 spaces

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want to write a program that uses nested loops to draw this a pattern that looks like this with hashtags:

```
##
# #
#  #
#   #
#    #
#     #
```

the program should stop inserting spaces between the two hashtags once 5 spaces have been inserted (meaning there should be 5 spaces between both hashtags in the last line). you have to insert one space for the first, two for the second, three for the third and so on.

right now, i've only done this, and i can't figure out how to use a nested loop or why you even need one.

```
x="##"
for i in x:
    print(" ".join(x))
```

Comment: You don't need a nested loop. `" "*n` will make `n` spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Print variable length space between two #s like this:

```
for i in range(6):
    spaces = ' '*i
    print(f'#{spaces}#')
```

Update:
The first line has no spaces between hashtags so the script was updated to print the first line correctly.

Comment: What's the list for?

Comment: It's called list comprehension to make for loop more concise.  You can write for loop without list syntax too.

Comment: Don't use a list comprehension if you don't need the list result. It's not a general replacement for loops.

Comment: Agreed, Thanks for your comment @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

```
for r in range (5):
    for c in range (1):    
         space = ' '
         total = space * r
         print ('#',total,'#',spe='')
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.